# Understanding integrals double meaning

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I would like to understand why the integrals represent 2 things:

1. If we only do an integral without bounds on $f(x)$, the integral gives us the function $F(x)$ that, when differentiated, gives us the original function $f(x)$.
2. If we do an integral with bounds $[a,b]$ on $f(x)$, it gives us the area under $f(x)$ by evaluating the difference $F(b) - F(a)$.

Why does $F(x)$ represent the area under $f(x)$ as well as the first point?

Comment: In fact, it is an astonishing result that 1 and 2 are related at all. The connection is provided by the FTC, which relates the development of the definite integral by Riemann sums, to the process of antidifferentiation,  See for instance the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

Comment: @user3911311 Please note that the site works better if there is some feedback. You can have a look at: meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/165400

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the integrals in 1 and 2 are rather similar symbols for rather different things:

1. This "integral without bounds" does not define a function, because there are many functions whose derivatives are equal to a given function. So at this point there is no new concept, but just a new symbol for the concept of *derivative*: $F(x)=\int f(x) dx$ must only be understood as a synonym for $F'(x)=f(x)$.
2. There is the problem (in fact much older than derivatives) of computing *areas*. To formalize it, we represent an area as $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ and define it as the limit of the sum of the small rectangular areas obtained by partitioning the enclosed area in infinitely-many portions.

Then, in order to solve problem 2, we define a function by arbitrarily establishing a left-hand bound of the area and moving the right-hand bound:
$$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$$
But we have not done anything yet, this is just a tool to rephrase the problem of computing areas as computing values of $F(x)$.

Now, the revolution (by Newton and Leibnitz): we cannot say anything about $F(x)$ itself, but we do know how it increases. The rate of increase of $F(x)$ at a point $x$ is precisely $f(x)$. (The graphical intuition is that any time we move the right-hand bound, we are adding a thin rectangle of height $f(x)$). So this is the impressive achievement known as Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: relating the concepts of derivative and area by the formula:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(t) dt=f(x)$$

So, the practical consequence is that if you are able to find some function $F(x)$ with $F'(x)=f(x)$, then you know that there is a constant $C$ such that:
$$\int_a^x f(t) dt=F(x)+C$$
Now, substitute at $a$ to get:
$$C=-F(a)$$
and substitute at $b$ to get:
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx=F(b)+C=F(b)-F(a)$$

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, to reiterate the admonishing of calculus teachers everywhere, don't forget the $C$! In other words, if $F$ is a differentiable function such that $F'=f$, then so is $F'+C$ for any $C\in\mathbb R$. We would write this
$$\int f(x)\ \mathsf dx = F(x) +C. $$
So really, the indefinite integral maps functions to equivalence classes of functions.

In the second case, this is only true if $f$ is a continuous function.